# Creating a template using a specific slug name, for a page with a parent page

Tags: pages, templates, slug

I have always preffered to create layout templates for specific pages by creating a filename the same as the slug.

So for example:

**Page Title**: Contact Us

**Page Slug**: contact-us

**Filename of template to be used**: page-contact-us.php

This always works fine for me.

However, I have one page that has a *parent* page. The page, with the slug *executive-search* has a parent of *employers*

For some reason, the file `page-executive-search.php` is not picked up as the default template for this page. This has worked fine throughout the site except for this one page. I have double-checked the page slug and it is `executive-search` but the `page-executive-search.php` template is not being used.

I do not wish to declare this as a global template to be selected from the drop-down on the edit page. I do not wish to make it chooseable through that menu. I wish it to automatically apply to a page with the slug `executive-search`

I am thinking this is something to do with it having a parent page. The full URL is:

`http://mysite.co.uk/employers/executive-search`

So where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The code used to make this decision by WordPress is [`get_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template/). The pagename version (`page-{slug}.php`) is pulled from [`get_query_var( 'pagename' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/), you can use this in your `page.php` template to see what it outputs when visiting the child page.

```
<?php echo get_query_var( 'pagename' ); ?>
```

This mostly just means that the parent slug is ignored so `/employers/executive-search/` and `/executive-search/` and `/random/executive-search` will all use the same page template of `page-executive-search.php` if available.

Or you can just use the `ID` of the page `page-NN.php`

Comment: Nope, not the case. Move page out of parent, template works. Move it in, stops working.

Comment: Did you add the code provided to your template to see what the `pagename` query_var is? This should give you the suffix you need to use.

Comment: Too late, don't care anymore! ;P Haven't add `pagename`, but have tried it with `index.php?pagename=` and I'm pretty sure it was the same slug as you'd expect.